# Jquery ui tab hidden div appearing on main tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm not sure exactly how to describe/ask this so I'll give it my best shot.  I am using add tab functionality in jquery's tabs.  On the first tab I have a jqgrid which I use to select items to open in a new tab.  When an item is selected the new tab is created successfully, but a div is added below the jqgrid which looks something like the following (white space added).  What might I be doing wrong to cause this phantom div to show up?  I found this using firebug, but since I haven't switched tabs yet nothing should be showing up right?  Also, it appears that 2 divs are created for each addtab I do.  Is 2 normal?
EDIT: 2 is not normal, the example code does not create two on the jquery ui website.

```
<div id="ui-tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-tabs-hide"></div>
```

Thanks.

Code used for addtab.

```
function addTab() {
    var selected_row = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam',('selrow'));
    $tabs.tabs('add', selected_row, selected_row);
}
```

And the tab template.

```
tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
```

Edit: Basically adding a tab is creating two divs.  IDs that are odd are actually wanted, and even ids are not.  (id a div with id="ui-tabs-3" is correct, but another tab is added as well which is of id="ui-tabs-2".  The 2 is not wanted.)  Nowhere am I telling it to add two tabs, and the even numbered stuff is dumby and has nothing, but I believe it is causing the crazy white space to appear and grow every time I add a new tab.  Any ideas?  I'm not doing anything complicated and can't pull code apart any further I don't think without taking away the add functionality itself.

Thanks.

Edit: And the tab init stuff as well?  Am I missing something obvious?  Seems like 6 lines of code involved and one would think I would see what I screwed up?

```
var $tabs = jQuery("#tabs").tabs({
                    //tabTemplate: "<li><a href='http://localhost:8000/tickets/byId/#{href}/'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
                tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
                ajaxOptions: {
                    error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                        jQuery(anchor.hash).html("If you're reading this then something didn't go right....oops.");
                    }
                }
            }).bind("tabsselect",function(event,ui){
                if (ui.index == 0) {
                    $grid.trigger('reloadGrid');
                }
            });
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging to see if addTab is possibly being called more than once, causing the extra tab?

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker: I don't think it is.  But I can't figure out how to figure that out using firebug.  However, if it were being called two times then I think my tabs would show up more than once themselves.  The extra divs that are being created don't line up with anything.  Also if it were being called twice I would expect two tabs identical, as the row is still selected in the jqgrid which means the second call should still open the same tab based off that first line of my addTab function.  Does that sound logical?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense--You could place a breakpoint in that function in Firebug and see when it gets hit. (here's how: http://getfirebug.com/javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this bug answers my question.

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5069